# Credit Card Form using RXjs

Tags: form, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to improve my skills and I'd like to work on avoiding bad practices and mistakes.

Can anyone skim over my code and point out what should have been implemented more efficiently or in a more compact way?

I am a newbie to `RXJS` and I would appreciate if you give some hint on organizing the code (pipes, eventListeners and the way I did it)

As you can see in my code I've three kinds of events there: `click`, `keydown` and `change`.

```
const inputs$ = merge(
  TypingEvent.numberTyping$, 
  TypingEvent.holderTyping$, 
  TypingEvent.cvvTyping$,
  );

  const change$ = merge(
    TypingEvent.monthSelect$,
    TypingEvent.yearSelect$
  );

const general = merge(
  clickEvent.cvv$, 
  inputs$,
  change$
  ).subscribe(console.log);
```

**Click**: I used one general pipe for all click events because their functionality is quite similar and basing on my base click event I created another pipe for `cvv` input element. 
I am not sure whether the approach of my focus implementation on a certain card field is a good practice because I'm using a lot of `regular expressions` and `recursive functions`.

*like this one:*

```
if (!(/^(card-)/i.test(eventGroup))) {

    clickEvent = {
      type: e.type,
      surface: 'away',
      overlay: {
        front: overlay,
        back: overlayBack
      },
      event: e
    }
```

**KeyDown**: Here I seem to have separate event handlers for each input because their functionality is different in formatting and displaying data. 
At first, I thought I would do common rules and then put `specific pipes` on top of them for each `input`. But then just used common pipe operators for each input because when I based specific rules on top of my base pipe for the event invoked as many times as many inputs I had.

```
const refactorCardEvent = (input: string) => map( event => {
  const e: ITypingEvent = event;

  const target = e.target;
  const eventGroup = findWrapper(target, 'data', 'picker');

  const refactored: ITypingEvent = {
    type: 'typing',
    lastKey: e.key,
    eventGroup,
    target,
    step: state[input].value.length,
    e
  }

  return refactored;

});


// Card number typing event
export const numberTyping$ = fromEvent(findElementByDataValue(form, { key: 'picker', value: 'card-number' }), 'keydown')
  .pipe(
    preventDefault(),
    filterKeys('digits', 16, 'number'),
    refactorCardEvent('number'),
    updatingState('^[0-9]$', 'number'),
    formatCardNumber(),
    displayingNumber()
  );
```

**Change**: Here are a few maps only but if I did something wrong I would appreciate your hints and experience.

---

Very often I had a mess with highlighting some variables in the code because of types. I seem to use proper types there but it says that event lacks something, for instance: `KeyBoardEvent`. A lot of red warnings in the code. So you have this problem too or what have I done wrong assigning types?

For overlay elements would it be better to create it on a click or to have it in the code like I did it?

What is the best practice at filtering keys and separating from the ones like `Control`, `Alt` and others.

*The way I implemented that*:

```
const filterKeys = (type: string, length: number, relatedState: string) => pipe(

  map(event => {
    let b: boolean;

    if (type === 'digits') {
      const t = new RegExp(/(\bDigit\S+)/, 'i');

      b = /^(\bTab\b)/i.test(event.code) || t.test(event.code) || /^(\bBackspace\b)/i.test(event.code);

    } else if (type === 'keys') {
      const t = new RegExp(/(\bKey\S+)/, 'i');

      b = /^(\bSpace\b)/i.test(event.code) || /^(\bTab\b)/i.test(event.code) || t.test(event.code) || /^(\bBackspace\b)/i.test(event.code);

    }

    const l = (/^(\bBackspace\b)/i.test(event.code) && state[relatedState].value.length !== 0) || (state[relatedState].value.length < length && !/^(\bBackspace\b)/i.test(event.code));

    return (b && l) ? { success: true, event } : { success: false };

  }),

  filter(event => event.success),

  map(event => event.event)

);
```

Any hints on engineering, structure or anything whatsoever it is are highly appreciated

The whole code is here: [Credit Card Form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/challenge-credit-card-form)